# HTTP Status code for content unavailable without a redirect

Tags: html, http-status-codes

I'm trying to find the correct HTTP status code for a page where the content is temporary unavailable however there is no redirect, instead a message is displayed on the page informing the user the content is temporarily unavailable.

`307 Temporary Redirect` isn't applicable as there is no redirect.

`404 Not Found` might possibly be applicable, however I'm not sure if this is the correct response to give as the content is found, just not available.

`410 Gone` isn't applicable as the content will be available again some time in the future.

None of the other codes seemed even remotely applicable. Does anyone know the correct code to use and can explain why?

Comment: What qualifies as a redirect? Redirecting the user to a page with a message that says the content is temporarily unavailable seems like it would qualify as a redirect. Technically, a 404 error page would seem like it would qualify as a redirect as well. I could be very wrong on this. It seems like we need to know the true definition of redirect. I would assume though that if I'm on your site and you take me to any other page than the one I requested, it would qualify as a redirect.

Comment: You're not actually going to another page though, your URI doesn't change at all. The 307 expects another header with a URI, which I wouldn't be providing. The message is provided on the page instead of the usual content.

Comment: I guess that is true. That makes sense.

Comment: If I can't find a suitable answer to this I'm tempted to change it and make it redirect just so the 307 fits, though I'd rather not have to.

Comment: Honestly, for your situation that sounds like it may be the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the 4XX series of responses are appropriate here. From [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-65):

> The 4xx class of status code is intended for cases in which the
> client seems to have erred. Except when responding to a HEAD request,
> the server SHOULD include an entity containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.

With this in mind, I think 403 forbidden is the most appropriate:

> 

10.4.4 403 Forbidden

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it.
> Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated.
> If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make
> public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the
> reason for the refusal in the entity.  If the server does not wish to
> make this information available to the client, the status code 404
> (Not Found) can be used instead.

I suggest this for three reasons:

2. It's not an exotic code, so it will work fine in the browser. This, to me, is the most important reason - you will be able to serve a page that explains why the content isn't available, and you can be fairly certain it will be displayed correctly.
3. It's appropriate for the server to say "I understand your request, but I won't serve you that content at this time", and that's exactly what the first two lines of the description say.
4. It doesn't explicity say "forget you ever knew about this content" to any robots (or for that matter, people).

---

For completeness, here's why I ruled out the other response code categories:

> **2XX** Success: This class of status code indicates that the client's request was
> successfully received, understood, and accepted.

- But, we're not accepting the request in this case. I don't think 2XX is right.

> **3XX**  Redirection: This class of status code indicates that further action needs to be
> taken by the user agent in order to fulfill the request.

- I suppose that you *could* argue "further action" to mean "please wait until the content is available before trying again", but reading the other 3XX codes, "further action" usually means "immediate redirect", which as you've already pointed out, isn't appropriate.

> **5XX** Server error: Response status codes beginning with the digit "5" indicate cases in
> which the server is aware that it has erred or is incapable of
> performing the request.

- Nothing has gone wrong on the server, you just don't want to serve the content right now.

Comment: Actually your reasoning behind this makes a lot of sense. The page has been temporarily blocked from public view and forbidden access with no chance of authentication matches everything I'm looking for. Thank you =)

Comment: You're very welcome! I updated the answer with some of the reasoning for not selecting the other codes, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP STATUS CODE `204`

i.e. NO CONTENT

Read More about it here:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

section 10.2.5

i.e.

`The server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content.`

Comment: 204 explicitly states you can't provide any content after the HEAD tag. I am.

Comment: I don't agree that this is a 204 case - "If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent.", which provides no opportunity to give feedback to the user.

Comment: Makes sense, then i think 404 is best case in this scenario since you are providing content also to user which is not the actual content that has to be served at this url. 404 exactly do this. That is Information you are looking for here on this url is not available.`This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.`